# MongoDB creates array of arrays in $group $push instead of flat array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to group a set of documents after an $unwind operation. My documents look like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cdb5b5acadf5100019da2f4"), 
    "allowedLocations" : [
        {
            "type" : "country", 
            "value" : "world", 
            "label" : "World"
        }
    ], 
    "disallowedLocations" : [
        {
            "type" : "country", 
            "value" : "CF", 
            "label" : "Central African Republic"
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "country", 
            "value" : "CN", 
            "label" : "China"
        }
    ], 
}

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cdb5b5acadf5100019da2f4"), 
    "allowedLocations" : [
        {
            "type" : "country", 
            "value" : "US", 
            "label" : "United States of America"
        }
    ], 
    "disallowedLocations" : [
        {
            "type" : "country", 
            "value" : "CA", 
            "label" : "Canada"
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "country", 
            "value" : "MX", 
            "label" : "Mexico"
        }
    ], 
}
```

I want to group them by _id and then concatenate the allowedLocations and disallowedLocations arrays into one.  The group stage in my pipeline looks like this:

```
{ 
    "$group" : {
        "_id" : "$_id", 
        "allowedLocations" : {
            "$push" : "$allowedLocations"
        }, 
        "disallowedLocations" : {
            "$push" : "disallowedLocations"
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, the result I get is not a document with both arrays concatenated, but an array of arrays, each element of the array being the array of each document:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cdb5b5acadf5100019da2f4"), 
    "allowedLocations" : [
        [
            {
                "type" : "country", 
                "value" : "US", 
                "label" : "United States of America"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "type" : "country", 
                "value" : "world", 
                "label" : "World"
            }
        ],
    ], 
    "disallowedLocations" : [
        [
            {
                "type" : "country", 
                "value" : "CF", 
                "label" : "Central African Republic"
            }, 
            {
                "type" : "country", 
                "value" : "CN", 
                "label" : "China"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "type" : "country", 
                "value" : "CA", 
                "label" : "Canada"
            }, 
            {
                "type" : "country", 
                "value" : "MX", 
                "label" : "Mexico"
            }
        ]
    } 
}
```

Is there a way to produce a flat array with only objects as elements? I also tried with $concatArrays before the push but that creates more arrays inside the arrays.

Comment: Why don't you just `$unwind` the `disallowedLocations` and `allowedLocations` before executing the `$group`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two solutions here. You can either run [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) on both arrays to get single `allowed` and `disallowed` `location` per document and then run your [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) stage:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$allowedLocations"
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$disallowedLocations"
    },
    { 
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$_id", 
            "allowedLocations" : {
                "$addToSet" : "$allowedLocations"
            }, 
            "disallowedLocations" : {
                "$addToSet" : "$disallowedLocations"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

or you can run your [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) first and then use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) to flatten `allowedLocations` and `disallowedLocations`:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    { 
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$_id", 
            "allowedLocations" : {
                "$push" : "$allowedLocations"
            }, 
            "disallowedLocations" : {
                "$push" : "$disallowedLocations"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            allowedLocations: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$allowedLocations",
                    initialValue: [],
                    in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }
                }
            },
            disallowedLocations: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$disallowedLocations",
                    initialValue: [],
                    in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: the first solution should have `$addToSet` instead of `$push` to avoid duplicate entries in array.

Comment: @VikashSingh that's true, thanks. Nonetheless I would prefer second one ;)